# Spyder: An error occurred while starting the kernel

Tags: python, tensorflow, ipython, anaconda, spyder

I am getting this error: An error occurred while starting the kernel

I have already tried
1. setuptools command
2. updating spyder
3. Uninstalling and Installing
4. Reading almost every responses
5. The following is the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\AHII\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 280, in 
    main()
    File "C:\Users\AHII\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 248, in main
    from ipykernel.kernelapp import IPKernelApp
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ipykernel'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\AHII\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 280, in 
    main()
    File "C:\Users\AHII\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 248, in main
    from ipykernel.kernelapp import IPKernelApp
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ipykernel'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\AHII\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 280, in 
    main()
    File "C:\Users\AHII\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 248, in main
    from ipykernel.kernelapp import IPKernelApp
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ipykernel'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\AHII\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 280, in 
    main()
    File "C:\Users\AHII\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 248, in main
    from ipykernel.kernelapp import IPKernelApp
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ipykernel'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\AHII\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 280, in 
    main()
    File "C:\Users\AHII\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 248, in main
    from ipykernel.kernelapp import IPKernelApp
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ipykernel'
```

Answer (score 0):

try to install `ipykernel`

```
pip install ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user
```

some [docs](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-different-environments) that can help you from ipython

Comment: Did, No difference @Zimdero

Comment: @ImageCheck i add another line of code, can you execute this and try again ?

Comment: Did, No difference again. @Zimdero

Comment: @ImageCheck try to upgrade ipython, `pip install --upgrade ipython`

Comment: Did. No difference @Zimdero. So I used 'conda remove ipykernel' and 'pip uninstall ipykernel' and again did 'pip install ipykernel'. This resulted in Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\image\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\notebook-5.5.0.dist-info\\METADATA'. Now when I use **C:\Users\IMAGE>python -m ipykernel install --user** I get **(base) 
C:\Users\IMAGE\Anaconda3\python.exe: No module named ipykernel**